# Offsite media streaming setup

Tags: php, scalability, media

I've got a media-rich site that's going just beyond the what our server can handle in terms of storage.  Estimate between 500 gigs and 2 terabytes.

The media is uploaded through the website usually 500k to 30 megs at a time and are just videos and photos users have uploaded.

Using the PHP FTP functions the media is then copied from the temp directory into the media directoy.

I'm looking for the best way to handle storing the file after the user has uploaded it.

**EDIT**

I have a cloud computing account with Mosso and all our sites are hosted on dedicated boxes with RackSpace (traditional).  My question applies to the actual process of getting media in to the site the way it currently is and then what to do next...

Comment: Please explain in greater detail

Comment: What would you like more details on?

Comment: Are you trying to work out the best way to get files from your users?

Comment: Not quite.  Once I've got the files, how to handle them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Rackspace Mosso](http://www.mosso.com/cloudfiles.jsp) or [Amazon S3 with Cloud Front](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)

Also think about using a [Content delivery network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Delivery_Network), to speed up your visitors load times.

Both have an Application Programing Interface that can be used with your internal systems, for uploading new content.

Twitter use Amazon S3 for users avatars.

Comment: I am already a Mosso member, I think my question wasn't necessarily that clear.  I'll edit